# cryptic python message homebrew

Tags: python, macos, bash, homebrew

```
.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps python3` to symlink these to /Applications.
```

What does the above message mean? Why should I run brew linkapps python3, or why not?

Comment: What command did you run to produce this output?

Comment: brew install python3

Comment: I have seen this elsewhere on web, but no explanation on what it means.

Comment: I left my Mac at home, so I can't verify this, but what could be happening is brew installed python3, but it couldn't automatically create the necessary symlinks. I can double-check and give you a better answer when I head home in a couple hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the python3 formula installed some .app bundles (e.g. the IDLE Python IDE). These .apps need to be visible outside of the Homebrew prefix for Spotlight etc to find them and Homebrew promises not to write outside of the Homebrew prefix without explicit permission from you. Running `brew linkapps` will symlink the apps into ~/Applications so that they become visible to the system as applications.

It's not necessary to run `brew linkapps` unless you want to use IDLE.